# Orientation acting weird when programmatically setting it up

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an issue with device orientation. I have a `UITabBarController` and I need all tabs to be Portrait except 1 tab that needs to be LandscapeRight.
I got it to work partially but consider this scenario where things go messy:

**Goal** : change from portrait to Landscape (using a button that changes the tab of the `UITabBar`.

**Works**: keep the screen physically in portrait and press the button that changes tabs. This changes the orientation to landscape once the new screen appears.

**Does not work**: keep the screen physically in landscape, while still in the portrait screen. Now tap on the button that changes the tab, and the result is that the screen does NOT rotate.

So if you understand my problem, depending on which orientation my device was physically (meaning how the user holds it before pressing the button) the results are different.

These are the relevant code snippets I am using to handle the situation:

in `UITabBarController`:

```
extension UITabBarController {

func portraitSelected() {
    AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait, andRotateTo: UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait)

}
func landscapeSelected() {
    AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight, andRotateTo: UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight)

}
override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}


override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
    get {
            return self.selectedViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations ?? .portrait

        }
    }
}
```

In the portrait view controller I have this code:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

and

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if let tabBar = self.tabBarController {
            tabBar.portraitSelected()
        }
    }
```

In the landscape view controller:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: 
    UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscapeRight
    }
```

and

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
if let tabBar = self.tabBarController {
    tabBar.landscapeSelected()
}
```

}

Finally, in `AppDelegate` I added these static functions (who are called in the above code)

```
var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait

struct AppUtility {
    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            delegate.orientationLock = orientation
        }
    }

    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        self.lockOrientation(orientation)
        if rotateOrientation.isPortrait {
            print("portrait")
        } else if rotateOrientation.isLandscape {
            print("landscape")
        }
        UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

Into the build settings I set portrait and landscapeRight as my supported orientations.

I have already searched every post I could find that is related to this and nothing solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I solved this by removing the landscape `UIViewController` outside of the `UITabBarController`.
I am now just changing the root view controller of the app back and forth when landscape/portrait is tapped:

```
@IBAction func landscapeTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let story = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let land = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "landscape") as! LanscapeViewController
    let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    window.window?.rootViewController = land
}
```

and this avoids the orientation problems.